# How to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(1+\sin(t)^2)\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

I'm struggling with this integral, I've tried different substitutions but i can't solve it.

$$\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(1+\sin(t)^2)\mathrm{d}t$$

I've tried to calculate both the primitive and the integral using WolframAlpha
But in the primitive appear the polylogarithmic functions with complex argument and for the integral it gives me a numerical approximation ($\approx 0.591331$)

Is there anyone able to solve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't think so, how do you turn that formula into my integral? (apart from putting b=1)

Comment: $a=1$ and $b=\sqrt{2}$ does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Richard Feynman's integral trick, let:
$$f(x):=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left(1+x\cdot \sin(t)^2\right)\mathrm{d}t\\\Rightarrow\;f'(x)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(t)^2}{1+x\sin(t)^2}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\pi}{2x}-\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+x\sin\left(t\right)^{2}}dt$$
$$\sin(t)^2=s\;\Rightarrow\; t=\arctan(\sqrt{s})\;\Rightarrow\; \mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{2\sqrt{s(1-s)}}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{\pi}{2x}-\frac{1}{2x}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+xs}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{s\left(1-s\right)}}\mathrm{d}s$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{\pi}{2x}-\frac{1}{2x}\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x+1}}\Rightarrow\; f(x)=\pi\ln\left(\sqrt{x+1}+1\right)+C$$
$$\text{Since }f(0)=0\Rightarrow\; C=-\pi\ln\left(2\right)$$
$$\text{So }f(x)=\pi\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x}}{2}\right)$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left(1+\sin(t)^2\right)\mathrm{d}t=f(1)=\pi\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\approx 0.5913306957$$